# How to fix string concatenation error in Python 3

Tags: python-3.x

When I run the code below, it begins to loop through and returns the time and length of temp_data, but before reaching 100 in the loop throws the error. If I update the code to sleep for 5 seconds instead of 1, it will make it through all 100 iterations.

```
start_date = 1483228800*1000 #jan 1 2017
pair = 'ETHBTC'
timeframe = '1m'

final_data = []

for _ in range(0,100):
        url = 'https://api.bitfinex.com/v2/candles/trade:'+timeframe+':t'+pair+'/hist?sort=1&limit=1000&start='+str(start_date)

    r = requests.get(url)

    temp_data = r.json()
    final_data = final_data+temp_data

    start_date = temp_data[len(temp_data)-1][0]+60*1000

    print(time.ctime(), len(temp_data))

    time.sleep(1)

print(len(final_data))
```

Error:

```
 Traceback (most recent call last):
      File   
    "/Users/michael/PycharmProjects/bot/venv/datasets/dataset.py", line 
    18,    in <module>
        start_date = temp_data[len(temp_data)-1][0]+60*1000
    TypeError: can only concatenate str (not "int") to str
```

Comment: Have a look at the contents of `temp_data`. This looks like that it does contain non-numeric values which you try to do arithmethic on.

Comment: [How to debug small programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/)

Comment: dhke - as far as I can tell, all of the data coming through is numeric and in the expected format. The last time that comes through before the code bombs is 1495477260000, so not sure why adding 60K to it wouldn't work

Answer (score 0):

you should convert `60*1000` to `str`.

```
start_date = temp_data[len(temp_data)-1][0] + str(60*1000)
```

Comment: Thanks, but this also results in an error:    start_date = temp_data[len(temp_data)-1][0]+str(60*1000)
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'int' and 'str'

Comment: Interesting error, according to 'TypeError: can only concatenate str (not "int") to str', I thought `temp_data[len(temp_data)-1][0]` was a `str` type data, so I suggested converting `60*1000` to `str`. But now I'm confused about it's type.